# Mathjax sites: Coloured background for MathJax code in app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Firstly, I know this is not a high priority, so sorry for proposing it at this stage.

I use the app to follow Crypto.SE, and think it would be easier and nicer to use if $M_a(t\cdot h)$ was treated in a similar way to code. I realise its impractical to expect the TeX generated in the app, but removing the delimiters and instead giving it a coloured background.

That is, similar to how `code` is treated to become `code`, I would like $math$ to become (for example) [image: math]

Comment: No experience with Crypto, but why green?

Comment: No reason, was trying to make sure my point was clear. I would have thought a final choice of colour could be made by someone who knows those sorts of things - I'm just a greedy user!

Comment: Wait, no compilation of LaTeX? The app became useless to me at once. :/